# unity5 primitive sphere color not changing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, colors

I have created lines using this,

```
LineRenderer line = new GameObject ("Line " + i.ToString ()).AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
line.SetColors (transRed, transRed);
Material lineGreen = new Material(Shader.Find("Particles/Alpha Blended"));
line.material = lineGreen;
```

and a sphere like this,

```
GameObject mySphere = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere) as GameObject;
Material myMaterial = new Material(Shader.Find("Particles/Alpha Blended"));
myMaterial.color = transRed;
mySphere.GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().material = myMaterial;
```

The colour transRed is,

```
transRed.a = 0.4f;
transRed.r = 1.1f;
transRed.g = 0.496078431f;
transRed.b = 0.0f;
```

My problem is that the line and sphere aren't coming in same colour. The line is of the colour I want, but the sphere is white. I'm using same shader and same colour variable. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I believe "Particles/Alpha Blended" does not care about .color setting. set color via shader's property like this:

```
    myMaterial.SetColor("_Color", transRed);
```

have a look at unity's documentation [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.SetColor.html)

Comment: @ree1991 sorry, how about this: material.SetColor("_TintColor", transRed); I found it here >> http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/how-can-i-access-tint-color-from-alpha-blended-particle-shader.108967/

Comment: but it doesn't work. the rendered colour comes pink. but my colour transred is not pink.

Comment: if it's pink like one object on [THIS](http://forum.unity3d.com/attachments/unity-core-assetbundles-png.66991/) image than probably you do not have a material assigned to the object.

Comment: no the shader is added and there i can see my colour as Tint Color. but the colour rendered is pinkish (i can see a ball of this colour on the left side of Particles/Alpha Blended, below Mesh Renderer in the inspector panel), though the transparency of my colour "transred" is applied.

Comment: one last shot. I just noticed your transRed.r is set to 1.1f this may mess things up. [set it in the range of 0 to 1](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.html). But I don't think this would be the cause of your problem.

Comment: thanks for the info. I thought the range was from 0 to 1.1f of 255 values. But now the line comes ok as usual, whereas the sphere comes white.

Comment: Do you know of any other way of generating 2d colour filled spheres/circles? @Nika

Comment: well, you can create a circle with transparent background in image editor software, then import as a sprite and attach [This Camera-facing Script](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=CameraFacingBillboard) to it

Comment: as for performance, solid non-transparent 3d sphere is way cheaper than a single transparent image.

Comment: actually I need to create a line with rounded caps, in android studio or so there is this, paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND) type thing. Can't create same with Line Renderer.

Comment: so probably you are looking for the [GL Class](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GL.html). it does exactly that.